# Dart How to compare 2 List <double> with rounded values?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, compare

I welcome everyone. Can you please tell me how to compare 2 List, rounding the values, for example, to two decimal places?

We have

```
var list1 = [3425,5559394484, 2351,4392210480, -2384,4831199322];
var list2 = [3425,5559394472, 2351,4392210480, -2384,4831199122];
```

You need to compare the values of the lists, rounding them up to 2 decimal places. the result should

```
be
print(ListEquality().equals(list1, list2)) // true
```

What is the best way to implement comparison? Thanks to everyone who will respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  var list1 = [3425.5559394484, 2351.4392210480, -2384.4831199322];
  var list2 = [3425.5559394472, 2351.4392210480, -2384.4831199122];

  final doubleEquality = EqualityBy<double, double>(_roundDouble);
  print(ListEquality(doubleEquality).equals(list1, list2));
}

double _roundDouble(double value) {
  return (value * 100).roundToDouble() / 100;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  var list1 = [3425.5559394484, 2351.4392210480, -2384.4831199322];
  var list2 = [3425.5559394472, 2351.4392210480, -2384.4831199122];

  // Create a function to round the values to 2 decimal places
  var round2 = (double number) => double.parse(number.toStringAsFixed(2));

  // Apply the rounding function to each element in the lists
  var roundedList1 = list1.map(round2).toList();
  var roundedList2 = list2.map(round2).toList();

  // Compare the rounded lists
  bool isEqual = const ListEquality().equals(roundedList1, roundedList2);

  print(isEqual); // true
}
```